# Некорректно работает "Design" в Qt Creator

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qtcreator

Суть в том, что некорректно отображаются компоненты в **`Design`**, в то время как проект компилируется абсолютно нормально (*QT 5.15.2*)

[image: Суть в том, что некорректно отображаются компоненты в Design, в то время как проект компилируется абсолютно нормально]

---

При чём при нажатии **`run`** проект отображается корректно:

[image: При чём при нажатии run проект отображается корректно]

---

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    qml_file = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.qml"
    engine.load(str(qml_file))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick обновил, так получается, что community Qt Creator версии 9.0.1 работает в целом криво, все компоненты устанавливались из его же установщика по итогу или дизайнер не работает или не компилируется проект, потому что python.exe не может найти main.py, я даже так и не понял из-за чего вылезла эта ошибка(саму ошибку понял) и как я её пофиксил + очень много дыр в этой IDE